# PHP CURL not working with UTF-8 Character

Tags: php, curl, utf-8, steam

I try to get steam item using api with PHP CURL request but problem is UTF-8 does not supported by CURL as request.

**My PHP Code**

```
$steam_key = $this->config->item("steam_key");
$name = "★ StatTrak™ Bayonet";
echo $url = "http://api.csgo.steamlytics.xyz/v1/prices/$name?key=$steam_key";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $response;
```

I am getting no any response.

Comment: and if you do `urlencode($name)` as parameter?

Comment: It is not the problem of UTF-8, it is that you need to encode the URL before using it for curl_init().

Comment: preferably encode the values, not the complete url (wat happens to the questionmark, slashes ampersants in the url else?

Comment: I used **urlencode** it gives me this url **http://api.csgo.steamlytics.xyz/v1/prices/%E2%98%85+StatTrak%E2%84%A2+Bayonet**

Comment: You can see also **name variable** also contains space

Comment: The API key error you are getting has nothing to do with urlencode, it doesn't mean that you don't need urlencode.

Answer (score 1):

Just encode your URL before using it with cURL.

Use `urlencode` to achieve this task:

```
$steam_key = $this->config->item("steam_key");
$name = urlencode("★ StatTrak™ Bayonet"); //Add function call here
echo $url = "http://api.csgo.steamlytics.xyz/v1/prices/$name?key=$steam_key";
```

Comment: I used **urlencode** it gives me this url **http://api.csgo.steamlytics.xyz/v1/prices/%E2%98%85+StatTrak%E2%84%A2+Bayonet?key=$steam_key**

Comment: I don't see your `?key=something` in your request. @Sadikhasan

Comment: @Sadikhasan look at your URL. It is not valid key. Do you have valid key?

Comment: Yes I have valid key but it secure so I cant share with you. This is not actually error of key.

Comment: Then use this key @Sadikhasan

Comment: If I apply urlencode then what happen **name variable** also contain space.

Comment: This is done in browser, because browser URL can convert UTF-8 sequnce to visible character. Just use with cURL and will work. add valid key to your string and that's all.

Comment: If directly hit url in browser then it working perfectly but with CURL it does not give any response.Can I guide me what an issue?

Comment: If directly hit url in browser then it working perfectly but with CURL it does not give any response.Can I guide me what an issue?